# How to put Text and TextInput in one line?

Tags: css, react-native

In my React Native 0.66 app component, a Text and TextInput needs to be in one line and occupied half of the screen width. Here is the view code used:

```
               <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', marginVertical: hp("1%")}}>
                        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row", width:wp("50%"), textAlign:"left"}}>
                            <Text style={styles.textTitle}>姓名:</Text>. //<<==Text
                            <TextInput   style={styles.textTitle} //<<==TextInput
                                        placeholder="姓名"
                                        onChangeText={changeName}
                                        defaultValue={name}
                                        multiline={false}
                                        />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row", width:wp("50%"),textAlign:"left"}}>. //<<==here is row
                            <Text style={styles.textTitle}>别号:</Text>
                            <TextInput style={styles.textTitle}
                                        placeholder="别号"
                                        onChangeText={changeAlias}
                                        defaultValue={alias}
                                        multiline={false}
                                        /> 
                        </View>
                </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
textTitle: {
        height:hp("10%"),
        fontSize:14,
    },

    container: {
        paddingTop:0,
    //justifyContent: 'center',     
    },
})
```

The problem with the view code above is that the `TextInput` was far below the `Text` even though both of them are in one `row` with the same `height`. What is missing here and how to align `Text` and `TextInput` in one line?

Comment: give style ={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"space-between",flexDirection:'row' }} to the parent View

Comment: If two are same `Text` or `TextInput`, then the code above align 2  elements horizontally. For 2 different elements like it is now, the code can't align them horizontally

Answer (score 1):

```
<View style={styles.row}>
  <Text style={styles.textTitle}>别号:</Text>
  <TextInput style={styles.textTitle}
    placeholder="别号"
    onChangeText={changeAlias}
    defaultValue={alias}
    multiline={false}
  /> 
</View>

const style = stylesheet.create({
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: "wp('50%')",
    textAlign: "left",
    display: flex,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
  textTitle: {...},
  container: {...}
})
```

I think you missed adding **display: flex;** to the View Content.
I replaced the style class **row**.
This will work for you. thanks.

Comment: One visible change after adding alignContents and alignItems to `row` is the row of name was put on first line. But somehow the TextInput is still far below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add display:flex to your View component.

Comment: There is no `display` in react native doc

Comment: @user938363 there is but its written as flex:1, plus u need to add one more property which is flexDirection:'row'

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
       <View style={{flexDirection:"row",flex:1,justifyContent:"center"}}>
           <Text style={{flex:1,textAlign:"center",backgroundColor:"blue",color:"white",height:40,paddingTop:10}}>Name</Text>
           <TextInput
               style={{backgroundColor:"red",flex:1,height:40}}
               placeholder={"hello"}
           />
       </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

I hope it solve your Query.

Comment: Somehow the `TextInput` is still far below the Text in the same row. One visible impact of adding flex:1 in textTitle is making the TextInput starting from right. But the code above (post as well) is working with 2 Text side by side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following mini-code for reference.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/hungry-meninsky-wv08l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I am trying to use React Native built in elements to render.

Comment: Ya I just shown you the style you need to apply for the elements